# Partial differentiation of $x^y+y^z+z^x $

Tags: partial-derivative

Considering the equation

$$x^y+y^z+z^x=k $$ defined for $x,y$ and $z$ all positive and $k$ is a positive constant.

To find $$\partial z/\partial x$$

Thanks.

Comment: Where is your problem ? What have you tried ? Does $y$ depend on $x$ ?

Comment: I tried taking logarithm and am stuck. $y$ doesn't depend on $x$.

Comment: Do you already know about the implicit function theorem ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I don't. Let me see

Comment: Got it. Thanks guys.